# Google Maps iOS SDK: optimizing finding a random street view

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-street-view

This code finds a random location on Google Street Map according to the bounding box of a country´s latitude/longitude. But it is still even with the bounding box way to slow - it can take up to a minute for a steet view photo to be found. What can I do to make this faster?

The delegated method from `GMSPanoramaView` checks if there was a valid panorama photo at the random position. if not tells to find a search for a new one.

```
// Delegate method of GMSPanoramaView that get´s called when didMoveToPanorama: is called
- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)view didMoveToPanorama:(GMSPanorama *)panorama
      nearCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    if (!panorama)
    {
        [self shuffleLocation];
    }

}

- (void)shuffleLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = [self randomLatitudeLongitude];
    [self.panoView moveNearCoordinate:newLocation];
}

 (CLLocationCoordinate2D) randomLatitudeLongitude
{
    CountryBBVal auBB = [[GGData SharedInstance] boundingBoxForCountry:Australia];

    double ranLongitude = [self randomDoubleBetween: auBB.NELng and: auBB.SWLng]; // Boundix Box
    double ranLatitude = [self randomDoubleBetween: auBB.NELat and: auBB.SWLat];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:4];
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];

    NSString *formattedNumberLng = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(ranLongitude)];
    NSString *formattedNumberLat = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(ranLatitude)];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D ranLatLng = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([formattedNumberLat doubleValue], [formattedNumberLng doubleValue]);
    //NSLog(@"ranLatLng: [%f] [%f]", ranLatLng.latitude, ranLatLng.longitude);




    return ranLatLng;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a non-deterministic way of finding a photo so you cannot control how long it takes. What you have coded is optimal and there is no performance improvement in code. Only your algorithm to do so is not optimal and you need to think of a better strategy to get to a random photo.

Comment: yes, If there were some way of moveNearCoordinate: (part of google SDK) not to be so picky and instead do what the name implies, and find the nearest coordinate this would work. I guess if if I want another moveNearCoordinate: method I need direct access to Google Maps API

Comment: Well, Google SDK is not a photo finding API, so think of a way to find photos in a bounding box.